# Where to store the user role securely in Front

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm working on a Vuejs app and the backend is returning only a token when a user login succefully.

What I wanna do, is to store somewhere the role of the user to use it in beforeEnter() in the router.

When the user logs in, a request fetchs the user informations (with the role). But when I refresh the page or when I change the route, I lose the states.

Si I was going to put the user infos in the LocalStage but I'm pretty sure that it's not safe at all because I can edit the role in Application (in Chrome)..

I need to have the role available all the time in the router but I don't know how except with the localstorage

Any solutions?

**EDIT: Because I got only a token as response from the backend. Is it good to directly call another request to fetch the userdata(including role) ?**

Like so:

```
export function loginUser ({ commit }, payload) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    LoginService.login(payload)
      .then(data => {
          console.log('enter')
          console.log(data)
            let tkn = data.access_token
            Cookies.set('tkn', tkn.toString())
            Cookies.set('cntd', 'true')
     --->   UserService.getB2cUserProfile()
            .then(data => {
                commit('LOGIN_USER', data)
                // will commit the data here to change the userInfos state
                resolve(data)

            })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Every time you need the user's privileges I would re-auth. The main concern is manipulating server-side data. If they abuse their privileges to display a hidden route that's fine, just make sure they fail auth if they try to submit anything.

Comment: So you would go for an axios call at every routes that controls roles? Like inside every BeforeEnter, you would put it?

Comment: Someone with more security expertise will hopefully chip in, but essentially; I'd make a call every time you re-render, and then save it in the state. This would marginally speed up loading of routes and would be fairly harmless? You might, for example, show an admin page that says `DELETE DATABASE` but onclick you'd re-auth them. So even though they can see stuff, they can't cause damage. If that makes sense? Obviously if your route contains sensitive data you reauth them. NEVER trust what the client says.

Comment: I would prefer to also prevent them to access to those type of page AND prevent any no authorized api call (but that second part is working without pb). But for the first one, I just don't know where to keep the role...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern) with [vue-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) which keeps the state the same in case you refresh the page with the help of cookies that is in sync with your states so whenever any state changes it will automatically get changed in the cookies and will help you for what you want (routing and on-refresh). When you get the token after login you can set the states and using persistence state you can mention the states in the paths that you want to save for the currently logged-in user. This can help you so much as after the user logs out from your website you can again set the role and other states to default.
So, In-store for vuex you can do something like this:-

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";

Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        auth: "false",
        role: "",
        anyotherproperty:""
    },
    getters: {
        getRole: state => {
            return state.role;
        },
        getAuth: state => {
            return state.auth;
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        createPersistedState({
            paths: ['auth', 'role'],
            storage: {
                getItem: (key) => Cookies.get(key),
                setItem: (key, value) =>
                    Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 7}),
                removeItem: (key) => Cookies.remove(key),
            },
        }),
    ],
    mutations: {
        //mutation will change the states like auth and role
    },
    actions: { //your actions which commit a mutation
    }

});
```

Then, In the router, you can use the global states defined in vuex and check if the user role is A or B or default and if auth is true and false.
This will help you manage everything very well.

Comment: I think I will try that out cause I don't find any secure solution thanks! But because I got only a token when an user logs in. Should I directly call again the api to fetch user data(including role)?. Because when the backed doesn't return any user info when login

Comment: I've edited the initial post to show you the code

Comment: alright everything works GREAT now with vue-persistedstate but now i can see the 'role' and the 'isLogged' data in the localstorage and I can easily modify it ... I guess I have to encrypt it?

Comment: Yes, you have to encrpt it also. For this you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-ls

Comment: Yeah after the user gets the token you can call another API and then you can save the data regarding roles in cookies. Also, use async-await when calling another API as after getting the roles and other data when have to update not before that or in middle. Also for using ls-secure you can see this example. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-persistedstate-with-secure-ls-encrypted-data-7l9wb?fontsize=14&file=/index.js:297-485   and tif his helps you can tick the answer or upvote it :)

Comment: thanks alot I got the solution now :) 
Just a last problem, is that I got 2 errors when I use secure-ls

Module '"../../@types/crypto-js"' has no exported member 'CipherHelper'.
Module '"../../@types/crypto-js"' has no exported member 'Encoder'.

I tried with "npm install --save @types/node" but I still have those errors :s
ESlint making the file "secure-ls.d.ts" red (in node_module/secure-ls).

Maybe you know by chance the solution

Comment: use ----->   import * as SecureLS from 'secure-ls';    this may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't ;/ not that line has an error : "const ls = new SecureLS({ isCompression: true });" This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof SecureLS' has no construct signatures.

Comment: check if this helps -------------> https://github.com/softvar/secure-ls/issues/21

Comment: Tried, even with some other previous versions. I guess that package isn't properly available in typescript. Do you have any other package than SecureLS? :) 

Thanks again!

Comment: I made it work with JS and no Typescript so I can back to JS for the moment

Thank you very much for your time!